# Improve responsetime from generic handler made by a jquery ajax call?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I have made a generic handler (.ashx) to fetch some database values using jquery ajax. I have a few questions:

1. Why is the first call to the handler always the slowest one?
2. Is there any way to decrease the response-time from the point that the HTTP-get/post is made until i get back a response from the handler? My current code looks something like this:

   ```
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        SOFAEntities ctx = new SOFAEntities();
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string systemKey = HttpContext.Current.Request["SystemKey"];

        try
       {
           SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET auditSheet = ctx.SYSTEM_AUDIT_SHEET.Where(s => s.SYSTEM_KEY == systemKeyDec).Select(s => s).OrderByDescending(s => s.AUDIT_SHEET_VERSION).First();
           HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(auditSheet));
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(new ErrorObj() { ErrorMessage = e.Message }));
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Any reason not to use web services for this? You wouldn't be manually serializing your business objects and wouldn't be writing strings to your response stream in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: There are several possible reasons, which all can add up to make the first request slower, like:

- The code has to be compiled / JITted
- There is no database connection in the pool, so one has to be established
- The database request is not cached in the datanase

2: You could serialise the objects manually, instead of using the generic serialiser, which uses reflection.

Comment: Is there any easy solution to any of the points above that people usually use when it comes to handlers?